# Substraction in a def with TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to substact a number I got from an entry to a global variable in a function.

Here's my code:

```
argent1=120

def nom1():
global master, argent1, e11, g2
e1.config(state="disabled")
g1=Label(master,text=e1.get()).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
g2=Label(master,text=argent1).grid(row=2,column=1)
g3=Label(master,text="Mise de #1:").grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
e11=Entry(master)
e11.grid(row=4,column=1)
e11.focus_set()
bou1=Button(master,text="Entrez",command=lambda:[devine1(),updatearg1()]).grid(row=4,column=2)

def updatearg1():
    global master, argent1, e11, g2
    g2.config(text=argent1-e11.get())
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Unrelated, but all those `g1`, `g2`, `bou1`, etc. are `None` as you assign them the result of `.grid(...)`

Comment: `g2.config(text=argent1-e11.get())` doesn't work and I don't know why?

Comment: @MarcBussière the first step is to break that into multiple statements. Get the value and store it in a variable so you can examine it. Then do the subtraction and examine the result. Then configure the label and examine what happened. You are trying to do too much in a single line of code, which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks it works!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
argent1=120
stringvar_name = tk.StringVar()


def nom1():
global master, argent1, e11, g2
e1.config(state="disabled")
g1=Label(master,text=e1.get()).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
g2=Label(master,text=argent1).grid(row=2,column=1)
g3=Label(master,text="Mise de #1:").grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
e11=Entry(master, textvariable=stringvar_name)
e11.grid(row=4,column=1)
e11.focus_set()
bou1=Button(master,text="Entrez",command=lambda:[devine1(),updatearg1()]).grid(row=4,column=2)

def updatearg1():
    global master, argent1, e11, g2
    g2.config(text=argent1-e11.get())
    the_math_to_be_worked_out = stringvar_name - argent1
```